# C# delete line from file over SSH

Tags: c#, ssh, sed, ip, cat

I'm using Renci SshNet to access a file via SSH from a C# program that I'm writing.

Using data from my app I create a line in a text file as below.

```
    sshclient.Connect();
                string data1 = textBox1.Text + ":";
                string data2 = textBox2.Text + ":";
                string ip = "${SSH_CLIENT%% *}" + ":";
                string data = ("\necho " + ip + data1 + data2 " >> file.txt");

                var cmd = sshclient.CreateCommand(data);
                cmd.Execute();
                sshclient.Disconnect();
```

The above code results in a line being added to the text file when I start my app as below, which is exactly what I want.

```
    123.456.789.000:data1:data2:
```

I would like to delete the line from the text file when my app closes, but so far I'm not having much luck.

Below is what I've tried...

```
    sshclient.Connect();
                textBox3.Text = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com");
                string ip = textBox3.Text;
                string del = ("sed -i '/" + ip + "/ d' file.txt");

                var cmd = sshclient.CreateCommand(del);

                cmd.Execute();
                sshclient.Disconnect();
```

The textbox does show the ip correctly when it's read from the web and added to the textbox.
But if I use the command above, the line is not deleted unless I manually type the ip into the textbox.

I have also tried

```
    string del = ("sed -i '/${SSH_CLIENT%% *}/ d' file.txt");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the IP had a space at the end which I couldn't see in the text box.